# Sony Tablet S Issue when Video is not pausing while called videoview.pause()

Tags: android, video

When I play a video, it's playing smoothly but after few minutes of playing, say after 10 minutes, I am getting pop up message as "Your 10 min of playing is over".

So, here when I am getting a pop-up message, ideally video should pause (as I am calling `videoview.pause())`  but the video is not pausing.

Actually when pop-up comes video is pausing just for 1-2 seconds and again it resumes from last played. But my requirement is that the video should not resume as long as I don't click any buttons (pop-up Dialog).

I am using same code for a Sony Tablet S, which I'm using in a Samsung Tablet, where the above mentioned issue is occurring.

So, I wanted to know whether the issue is because of OS or something else?

*Platforms used:*

Sony Tablet S : Android 4.0.3

Samsung  Tablet : Android 3.0.1

Comment: Post the code will look in to that ...

Comment: Hi,Arfin I think this is a device issue since i found that after playing video for time it pops-up with a message "Sorry this video cannot be played".This issue seems to be similar to the YouTube one.

Comment: Video, camera, audio or any hardware devices programming aspects differs from device to device so we should always try to write more generic and flexible codes which will supports for all the devices.

Comment: This issue is not solved yet, but i came to know that this issue is because of Device only!

Comment: Yea, but you should try with alternate ways.

Comment: I check for youtube video ,which also gives the same error!!!!!!!!

Comment: we used most generic code for the video player but still getting the issue